# Caching not working for associated entities unless lazy loading specified in mapping file

Tags: nhibernate

I am having a problem getting associated entities to be cached unless
they are specified (Not.LazyLoad() in mapping). If I build up a query
in Criteria or Linq the Main Entity is cached, but not associated
entities.

```
IList<NewsItem> news;
using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    Console.WriteLine("First Query");
    news = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(NewsItem))
        .SetCacheable(true)
        .SetFetchMode("Author", FetchMode.Eager) // associated entity eager loaded
        .List<NewsItem>();
}
foreach (var item in news)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Author: " + item.Author.Name); //works fine first time
}

using (var session = factory.OpenSession())
{
    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Second Query");
    news = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(NewsItem))
        .SetCacheable(true)
        .SetFetchMode("Author", FetchMode.Eager)
        .List<NewsItem>();
}
foreach (var item in news)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Author: " + item.Author.Name); //NHibernate.LazyInitializationException
}
```

I want to avoid having to eager load the associations via the mapping
files. Anyone else having a similar problem.

Any feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What query caching (`SetCacheable(true)`) does is store the ***IDs*** retrieved by the query; it then hydrates the objects one by one (hopefully, from the entity cache).

IIRC, when caching a query, FetchModes for related entites are not used, so the Author references are not being initialized.

It's worth noting that you shouldn't be using your entities outside a session, but here's a workaround:

```
news = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(NewsItem))
              .SetCacheable(true)
              .SetFetchMode("Author", FetchMode.Eager)
              .List<NewsItem>();
foreach (var item in news)
{
    var name = item.Author.Name;
}
```

This will force initialization of the proxies *inside* the sessions; that way you'll be able to use them afterwards.

Of course, you need to make sure both NewsItem and Author are cached, otherwise you'll actually *decrease* the performance by caching the query.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Diego - Re not using entities outside a session - I use a Unit of Work to connect to the repository and hydrate the objects. The unit of work completes and returns the entities via a viewModel. I don't want to access the entities outside the session and am trying to populate the viewModel inside the unit of work with the data it needs. I assumed it would have been the eager loaded associated entities too, but seems that is not the case. Seems I have to force the loading inside the unit of work.